# Short i stressed and unstressed in English accents without weak merger

Tags: pronunciation, weak-vowel-merger

According to all English vowel chart, there is only one short i sound, so, it is the same sound in posItion and in rosEs, in the accents without the weak merger ?
Thanks

Comment: I sense a slight difference in those two sounds, though not enough to be noticed unless you're listening for it.

Comment: I don't know what "the weak merger is", but the unstressed vowel of "roses" can also be schwa or backed from lax i, and is sometimes transcribed with barred-i.  I don't think there is a lot of agreement about the exact quality of English unstressed vowels.

Comment: The /ɪ/ is stressed in *position* and unstressed in *roses*. This means these two vowels are going to be pronounced differently (at least slightly) in many dialects of English. But if we tried to use a different IPA symbol for all the stressed/unstressed pairs of vowels, we might run out of symbols. And there's no reason to ... there are no minimal pairs because the stress is different. And the sounds are quite similar in most dialects.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603199/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quality of the KIT vowel in *position* and *roses* (for speakers who use a KIT vowel in such plurals) is likely to be slightly different, at least in terms of length. However, it is the same *phoneme* in both words for such speakers. The two phonetic vowels which might occur in each word would be allophones of the same phoneme. So such speakers would recognise the vowels in *position* and *roses* as being the same vowel, namely the KIT vowel:

- pəz**ɪ**ʃn
- rəʊz**ɪ**z

Comment: How do you know it's the same phoneme?

Comment: @GregLee Given that it's widely recognised to be, for speakers without a weak merger, let me turn that on it's head and ask you why we shouldn't think it is?

Comment: I asked first. .

Comment: @GregLee Tough!

Comment: @GregLee Don't really see the point rolling through basic phoneme stuff unless there's some reason.

Comment: Right.  I didn't think you knew.

Comment: @GregLee Really? I thought it was probably because you couldn't be bothered to look up *weak merger* and therefore didn't realise that *Rosa's* and *roses*, for example, would necessarily be minimal pairs in such varieties of English.