# IPA confusion for 'Aegis'

Tags: ipa

1. Merriam-Webster says:  \ˈē-jəs \ or  \ˈā-jəs\
2. Cambridge says: /ˈiː.dʒɪs/ for US
3. Oxfor says:     /ˈiːdʒɪs/

   1. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aegis
   2. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aegis
   3. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aegis

When I hear the sample pronunciations from the above three sources, I hear all of them same - but the IPA is different. Can anyone help me understand why!

Soft question: Few of my colleagues from US, tend to  pronounce 'Aegis' as /ˈe dʒɪs/ which is not what any of these dictionaries says. Any hint of what's going on here (as in, is the pronunciation trends changing for this word)!

Comment: MW does not use IPA. Your vowel choices include those of FLEECE, FACE, DRESS, and perhaps KIT.

Comment: @ tchrist - Is KIT mapping to vowel in /ˈe dʒɪs/!  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: For the second syllable, yes. For the first syllable, /e/ is the FACE vowel in some notations but the DRESS vowel in others.

Comment: NBC and Telemundo personality Jose Diaz-Balart (whose name is written without the accent on NBC News website) has the habit on English language broadcasts of pronouncing Hispanic names *in Spanish*, e.g., rolling the "r" in "Gutierrez" or "Almaguer." He does not anglicize the name; he pronounces it in a foreign language. Aegis and Aesop seem to raise the same problem.  Are we pronouncing them in English, or as transliterated Greek?  I say render unto Seezer what is Caesar's: "aegis" assonates with "fleece this.") (I know - Caesar is Latin, but same difference.)

Comment: @ remarkl - A good point, wondering how it is pronounced (IPA?) in Greek!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short i stressed and unstressed in English accents without weak merger](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258755/short-i-stressed-and-unstressed-in-english-accents-without-weak-merger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merriam-Webster doesn't use IPA. [Cambridge,](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aegis) [OxfordLD,](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/aegis?q=aegis) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aegis) transcribe these as /ˈiː.dʒɪs/, /ˈiːdʒɪs/, and  /ˈiːd͡ʒɪs/, respectively; despite the minor differences in notation, these dictionaries are all in agreement.